# Why can't I access HTML table in JS using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $nameArray = array(
    array("Andy", "Jackson"),
    array("Barry", "Obama"),
    array("Benny", "Franklin"),
    array("Georgey", "Washington"),
    array("Billy", "Clinton"))
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function shout(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
window.onload=initiate()

function initiate(){
  shout("initiate 0");
  var nameTable = document.getElementById("xyzTable");
  shout ("initiate 1 - nameTable is "+nameTable);
}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Blablabla</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id='xyzTable'>
    <?php 
      foreach ($nameArray as $pair){
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td>".$pair[0]."</td>
          <td>".$pair[1]."</td>
        </tr>";
      }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do that the content of the JS variable `nameTable` is `null`, as I can see in my web console.  Why is that?

Comment: Now that the problem is identified, voting to close as Too Localized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're executing `initiate` right away. I think you meant:

```
window.onload=initiate;
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Dumb, dumb, dumb...

Comment: @JDelage I would recommend [jQuery's] load/ready or an equivalent .. using onload can lead to "contention" in some environments.

Comment: *Strongly* recommend pointing out that Automatic Semicolon Insertion is the spawn of the devil. Include the semicolon. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Eek, thanks for noticing!